# Use a single bit as mask for a word(s)

Tags: assembly, x86, llvm, bmi

I am writing an LLVM pass module to instrument every single memory operation in a program, and part of  my logic needs to do some very hot binary logic on pointers.

How can I implement "bit ? u64_value : zero" in as few cycles as possible, preferably without using an explicit branch? I have a bit in the least significant bit of a register, and a value (assume u64) in another. If the bit is set, i want the value preserved. If the bit is zero, I want to zero out the register.

I can use x86 BMI instructions.

Comment: Is it possible to represent the bit differently?  For example, how about having a register contain `-1` if the bit is set, 0 otherwise?  If you could do so, you could use a single `and` instruction to apply the mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On AMD, and Intel Broadwell and later, CMOV is only 1 uop, with 1 cycle of latency.  Or 2 uops / 2 cycles on Haswell and earlier.  It's your best bet for conditionally zeroing a register.

```
xor  r10d, r10d   # r10=0.  hoist out of loops if possible

test    al, 1           # test the low bit of RAX, setting ZF
cmovz   rax, r10        # zero RAX if the low bit was zero, otherwise unmodified
```

(`test r64, imm8` encoding doesn't exist, so you want to use the low-8 register if you're testing a mask that's all zero outside the low 8 bits.)

If the bit-position is in a register, `bt reg, reg` only 1 uop on Intel and AMD.  (`bts reg,reg` is 2 uops on AMD K8 through Ryzen, but plain `bt` that sets CF according to the value of the selected bit is cheap on AMD and Intel.)

```
bt     rax, rdx      # CF = RAX & (1<<rdx)
cmovnc rax, r10
```

With both of these, the register you test can be different from the CMOV destination.

See https://agner.org/optimize/ for more performance info, and also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Answer (score 1):

`select` is your friend. It mostly compiles to `cmov` but the backends will take care it even if not. Semantically it's "if arg1 is true then arg2 else arg3", rather like ?: in C/C++/java. In the C++ API you call `SelectInst::Create(yourBool, yourInputValue, ConstantInt::get(i64, 0), instructionName, currentBlock);`.

You'll find life easier if you can concoct meaningful names for instructions. It doesn't matter at first, but as your code grows it simplifies debugging more and more.